# How to set an alert on the daily Google App Engine budget?

Tags: google-app-engine, alert

I've read the [budget alert docs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) and can only find a way to setup a total MONTHLY alert. However, App Engine will shut down your app if it exceeds its DAILY budget. I was unable to find a way to get an alert on approaching the daily limit. Anyone knows how we can set it up without writing cron jobs and code?

Comment: [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit) mentions new App Engine apps do not have the feature of setting a Spending limit, so I wonder if your app is being shut down by an old limit you had on the project. Have you considered [removing this spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console#removing_a_spending_limit), and using [the updated methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs) to control the cost of your app.

Comment: I'll explore the other options, thanks